# Using Ajax the first Time (plus Laravel) but i have problems understanding

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

today i tried to work with ajax for the first time. 
Im doing Requests in Laravel right now.

My regular Requests work fine. Views get passed in without a problem when i het the button.
Now im trying to get specific sites. 2 Problems appear.

1.) The **result is shown for a a second and disappears again**. Which is strange since im using the same code as in my other requests.

2.) Most of my pages dont work with the request. When i start them from another page i get **"MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:"**.
I dont really understand whats different about some of the pages. Since the whole PATH is defined inside the jquery.

Here is my code. Its simple, does not have any real functionality. Only for learning purpose.

```
AJAX
$(document).on('click','#getRoom', function(){
    $id = document.getElementById("roomNr").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: $rootPath + '/ajax/GetContent3/' + $id,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data){
            $data = $(data);
            $('#container').fadeOut().html($data).fadeIn();
        }
    });
```

_

```
My Route
Route::get('/ajax/GetContent3/{id}', array(
    'uses'  =>  'roomController@show2'
));
```

_

```
My Controller
  public function show2($id)
    {



        return view('pages.room2')->with('id',$id);
    }
```

_

```
My HTML Container
<div class="container" id="container"></div>
```

_

```
My FORM(INSIDE NAVBAR)
<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="roomNr" id="roomNr" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="getRoom">
        <input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    </form>
```

Its a simple approach but i want to learn slowly how to pass data.

Thanks for your help in advance!

*EDIT:
I figured out that the ajax request doesnt work at all on if sites are routed by more than one parameter (dont know how to say it so im giving an example).*

www.mysite.com/my_stuff/ -> **AJAX-Request works**

www.mysite.com/my_stuff/otherstuff/ **- AJAX-Request does NOT work.**

EDIT2:

```
RELEVANT PHP ARTISAN ROUTE:LIST

    METHOD               URI               ACTION
    GET|HEAD  | ajax/GetContent  | App\Http\Controllers\ajaxController@loadContent
    GET|HEAD | ajax/GetContent2| App\Http\Controllers\ajaxController@loadContent2
    GET|HEAD | ajax/GetContent3/{id} | App\Http\Controllers\roomController@show2
```

EDIT 3

```
GET|HEAD| todo/{id}|| App\Http\Controllers\pagesController@show                  |
```

EDIT 4:
MY routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('admin/createroom', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'roomController@create'
]);

Route::post('admin/createroom', 'roomController@store');



Route::get('todo', 'pagesController@index');

Route::get('image','pagesController@image');

Route::get('todo/create', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'pagesController@create'
]);

Route::get('profile', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'pagesController@profile'
]);
Route::post('todo','pagesController@store');


Route::get('todo/{id}','pagesController@show');


Route::controllers([
    'auth'       => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password'   => 'Auth\PasswordController',

]);

Route::get('logout','pagesController@doLogout');

Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');

Route::get('home', 'pagesController@index');

Route::get('/ajax/GetContent', array(
    'uses'  =>  'ajaxController@loadContent'
));

Route::get('/ajax/GetContent2', array(
    'uses'  =>  'ajaxController@loadContent2'
));

Route::get('/ajax/GetContent3/{id}', array(
    'uses'  =>  'roomController@show2'
));
```

app/config.php defines the url like this:

```
'url' => 'http://localhost/app2',
```

So when I am on "http://localhost/app2/public/todo" and push the ajax-button it works.

When I am on "http:localhost/app2/public/todo/1" and push the ajax-button it does NOT work.

Answer (score 1):

I am an Idiot.
I did not realize that the js-files are not loaded in the subroutes.

So instead of

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

I now use

```
<script src="<?php echo url();?>/js/app.js"></script>
```

In the main blade template. So sorry for bothering but im still a Beginner.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem you have, "content showing then disappearing..." I think you have a problem in your jQuery code. The change of html, fadeIn and fadeOut are all done at the same time if you chain your calls like that.

You have to use the callback of fadeOut function to be able to change your html then fadeIn it only when the fadeOut is finished. To do that, you have to call your functions like that :

```js
$(document).on('click','#getRoom', function(){
    $id = document.getElementById("roomNr").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: $rootPath + '/ajax/GetContent3/' + $id,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data){
            $data = $(data);
            var container = $('#container');
            container.fadeOut(function() {
                container.html($data).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: adding return false; to the function actually fixed it. Just found the solution! But thank you very much!